# Inaccurate reputation increase in profile reputation tab

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, voting, upvotes

I understand that normally one upvote would reward 10 reputations to user, however, I noticed that when I clicked into the reputation tab under my profile after getting upvotes, the reputation increase would be more than the number of upvotes I've got.

For example, at the time of screenshooting, I have five upvotes to the answer of [R: How to count consecutive values across columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76236591/16647496), but the reputation would shown an increase of 90 reputations if I clicked on the reputation tab immediately when I received the upvotes (note the total rep for today is correct):
[image: immediate_reputation_tab]

The correct reputation would be shown after reloading the page:
[image: normal_rep]

I've noticed this phenomenon for a while now, not sure if others are also encountering it.

Comment: That's a known bug. It's been like that for 2 years. Just refresh the page.